# "bash: /snap/bin/jupyter: Permission denied" but "sudo: jupyter: command not found" when run with sudo

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

i installed jupyter using snap, and then tried to remove it by removing the snap jupyter folder, which i then recreated. I also pip installed and uninstalled jupyter lab a few times.

If i run jupyter lab, i get a permission denied

```
bash: /snap/bin/jupyter: Permission denied
```

but when i run with sudo, i get the following ( for any valid jupyter command ) :

```
sudo: jupyter: command not found
```

I would like to get rid of the snap version, and pip uninstall and install and run jupyter lab, but deleting and recreating the folder made it worse.

Comment: advice: I would tag it snap and Ubuntu as it seems OS-specific installation problem and not having much to to with any specific program.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo snap remove jupyter`? When you installed it with pip did you use `--user` option maybe? Did you install it in a virtual environment maybe?